# Why my listview style change when I loop the javascript twice?

Tags: javascript, html

I develop an android native application using phonegap and jquery mobile. I've made a function to create a listview style dynamically using looping `for..`. When I run the function for the first time, it works, the listview style is working, and match with the content. but when I press back button and run the function again, the style change (the listview style is gone) but the content still there. is my function wrong? how to solve this problem?

the screenshoot for more explanation:

- [this is the result when I press the back button and run the function again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIS2Y.jpg)

the codes for more detail:

```
function detail(kodenegara, koderesult)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://10.80.3.73/webservice/Service1.svc/json/weeklyflash/"+kodenegara,
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    var result = koderesult;

                    maks = -1;
                    for(i = 0; i < data[result].length; i++) {
                        if(data[result][i].bulan > maks) 
                        maks = data[result][i].bulan;
                    }

                    var loop_tipe = countTypesForBulan(data[result], maks);
                    var innerHtml = "";

                    for (i = 0; i < loop_tipe; i++){
                        a=i+loop_tipe;
                        b=a+loop_tipe;
                        innerHtml += 
                        "<div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='true'>"+
                        "<h3>"+data[result][i].type+"</h3>"+
                        "<table width='100%' border='1'>"+
                            "<tr>"+
                                "<td>&nbsp;</td>"+
                                "<td style='text-align: center'>"+data[result][i].bulan+"/2012</td>"+
                                "<td style='text-align: center'>"+data[result][a].bulan+"/2012</td>"+
                                "<td style='text-align: center'>"+data[result][b].bulan+"/2012</td>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                            "<tr>"+
                                "<td>Cash</td>"+
                                "<td style='text-align: right'>"+data[result][i].uang+"</td>"+
                                "<td style='text-align: right'>"+data[result][a].uang+"</td>"+
                                "<td style='text-align: right'>"+data[result][b].uang+"</td>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                            "<tr>"+
                                "<td>Qty</td>"+
                                "<td style='text-align: right'>"+data[result][i].total+"</td>"+
                                "<td style='text-align: right'>"+data[result][a].total+"</td>"+
                                "<td style='text-align: right'>"+data[result][b].total+"</td>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                        "</table>"+
                        "</div>";
                    }
                    $('#tipe').html(innerHtml);
                    $.mobile.changePage("#detail", "slide", false, true);

                    //show the page
                },
                error: function () { 
                    alert("ERROR"); 
                }
            });
        }

        function countTypesForBulan(resultArray, bulanVal) {
            var i,
                types,
                count = 0;
            for (i=0, types = {}; i < resultArray.length; i++)
                if (resultArray[i].bulan === bulanVal && !types[resultArray[i].type]) {
                types[resultArray[i].type] = true;
                count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
```

- [here is for simulation my project with jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seXmc/9/)

Comment: Where is the code for review? If this is more of a problem of broken code I'd suggest [SO] otherwise please help us by adding some code. Thanks. EDIT:- I should have prefaced that with .... "I'm too lazy to go to paste bins for code" ?

Comment: @JamesKhoury well, my code is working but I think there is some bugs in my code and need to be review. I've update my thread now, thank you..sorry :p

Comment: thanks its easier to read code when its in the thread. I'm not sure whats wrong with this. Could you also provide a sample response from that url?

Comment: here is the url result:
`{"GetReportIdResult":[{"bulan":"4","total":"1728","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"8796383"},{"bulan":"4","total":"572476","type":"ESL","uang":"5863408410"},{"bulan":"5","total":"4761","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"134877865"},{"bulan":"5","total":"648663","type":"ESL","uang":"6645764498"},{"bulan":"6","total":"5762","type":"CHEESE1K","uang":"293393832"},{"bulan":"6","total":"594942","type":"ESL","uang":"6088671790"},]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with your code in terms of why it gives you different styles. I would however ensure you have a consistent coding standard.

For example my coding standards usually include:

1. Always declare variables. Variable `maks` is never declared here (I'm going to assume it is never declared.) Change it to `var maks = -1;`
2. Always use `{` and `}`. This will ensure you don't screw up a block.

   ```
   if(data[result][i].bulan > maks) 
       maks = data[result][i].bulan;
   ```

   would become:

   ```
   if(data[result][i].bulan > maks)
   {
       maks = data[result][i].bulan;
   }
   ```

   Its just proofing for us who make mistakes from time to time.
3. make local variables where possible

   ```
   if (resultArray[i].bulan === bulanVal && !types[resultArray[i].type]) {
       types[resultArray[i].type] = true;
       count++;
   }
   ```

   could be:

   ```
    var current = resultArray[i];
    if (current.bulan === bulanVal && !types[current.type]) {
       types[current.type] = true;
       count++;
   }
   ```

   It means less look ups. Most of the time its easier to read.

Comment: okay, I'll update my code as your advice. Thank you very much :))

Comment: @blankon91 It might help to see the outer for loop that calls this code. There might be something there that is the root of your problem.

Comment: here is the outer that call this code http://pastie.org/4201837

Comment: @blankon91 Your original post seemed to suggest this was created dynamically in a `for..` loop

Comment: yes, I want it created dynamically listview

Comment: or maybe you can review my new code http://jsfiddle.net/seXmc/

Comment: @blankon91 ... you can't do cross domain Ajax requests. I can't give you any more review on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3995/discussion-between-blankon91-and-james-khoury)

Comment: well, what if we ignore that cross domain ajax request, and assume that the json string is hard coded, can you review whats wrong with my function and maybe somethiong wrong with my way to call the function?